# (How) Is it appropriate to thank the instructor after an excellent class?

Tags: etiquette, communication

I'm an Erasmus student and I've had pleasure to meet a really great teacher who taught me more than anyone before. I would like to show my appreciation and thank her, but I'm leaving a week before the end of the course - and the grades release.
I want to be polite, appreciative and show my respect not to be a "teacher's pet" (I'm an Erasmus, I don't care about the grades, just the learning experience).
Should I came to her after the class and simply thank or send and e-mail or I'll be just making a fool of myself?

Comment: Why not an email after the course finishes? You will be more free to speak your mind.

Answer (score 5):

You won't be making a fool of yourself, we all appreciate a "thank you"...

You can choose to say in person, and your idea of "thank you for the learning experience" is good.

An email can also be fine, which you can send to arrive after the grades come out if that is a concern for you.

Do it, it will be fine. Or do both...

Edit, as Bob points out a handwritten note or card is also good.

Comment: Email is good.  An actual written note with a stamp on it is even better.  I've saved, and treasure, such a note from a student from long ago.

Answer (score 3):

Thanking a prof in person is a tremendous thing to do. I recommend it highly. I also recommend returning later (years, perhaps) and thanking her again if possible.

However, if you want to do it by email, also copy the department head or dean on your mail.

I doubt that grades enter in to it in any case. If you are sincere, it will be recognized and appreciated.